# WPF databinding to a TreeView from Code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, code-behind

so I have a treeView which works fine. But my problem is that I want to display different trees, of different Types without having to create one for every scenario in XAML. I know how to set the content of a listView from code behind, is the same possible for a treeView? My treeView right now looks like the following but obviously only works for Items of the Type CAN-Message:

```
<TreeView TreeViewItem.Selected="OnItemSelected" MouseDoubleClick="Tree_MouseDoubleClick" Name="tree">
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type srcM:CANMessage}" ItemsSource="{Binding Signals}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" (0x"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CANid}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=")"/>
        </StackPanel>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The thing is I have different scenarios. One for example where I only want to display the Signals List of the class ADTF (shown below) which is of the Type string.
And in another case I want to display the CANMessages list of the CAN Class and for each Message Element I want to set the signal list it contains as subelements (Which is implemented in the XAML example). I have a short version of said classes following:

```
public class ADTF : ISignalSource
{   
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Signals { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CAN: ISignalSource
{   
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<CANMessage> Signals { get; set; }
}
 public class CANMessage
{   
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Signals { get; set; }
}
```

So what I think I need to do is create a HierarchicalDataTemplate for every scenario. But I want to do it in code behind because it seems to take less code than implementing a HierarchicalDataTemplate in XAML for every scenario. Is there a way to o this?

Comment: Well, have you tried to apply what you did with the ListView to your TreeView? They should behave similiar given that they both are ItemControls.

Comment: @Freggar I tried. But the first Problem I run into is that I can't take the datatype out of the HierarchicalDataTemplate. And once I take out the template the list stays empty (which I guess makes sense since I don't tell it how to display) Is there any way to set the hirarchicalDatatemplate from Code behin maybe?

Comment: Oh maybe I misunderstood your question. Do you want to make different Templates for different Datatypes? If so, you can just define multiple `HierarchicalDataTemplate` inside of your `TreeView.Resources` for the different DataTypes. I have a hard time understanding what you actually want.

Comment: @Freggar Oh. That might actually be a solution. I didn't know you could do that. I just want to display trees containing different datatypes without having to implement a separate treeView for every scenario. Still, is it possible to generate the HierarchicalDataTemplate from Code behind? Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: Sorry I don't have much experience with setting DataTemplates from code behind, but my guess is you can. When setting them in code behind it is probably a easier to set `ItemTemplate` instead of adding children to `Treeview.Resources` since that might be statically linked. Maybe something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597342/how-to-dynamically-create-data-template-and-bind-treeview-hierarchical-data-in-c?

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in the TreeView and how are your types defined? Please edit your questions and clarify your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, You can use `Interface` to get this working.

**Similar question:** [wpf Treeview with three levels in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760316/wpf-treeview-with-three-levels-in/50763279#50763279)

Comment: I don't think that would work in my case because the lists I want to display are so different.

Comment: I would recommend to do it in XAML itself instead of doing it from code behind. 

You can introduce a `readonly` property in `CAN` class to return the Signals as a formatted string. Something like,

`public class CAN: ISignalSource
{   
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<CANMessage> Signals { get; set; }
    public List<string> Signals { get; }
}`

Or you can use `IValueConverter` to format your `CANMessage`. With this, you can use the same `Template` for both the clases.